# When selecting all cells in a row of datagridview, set the row to selected as property

Tags: c#, datagridview

Simply said - I want to handle the SelectionChanged event of a datagridview and if all the cells of a current row or rows get selected, to set the row propery "selected" to true, and if the selection changes and not all the cells are selected already, to unselect the row. I could manage to do it manually with a bunch of checks and loops, but I'm away from thinking it should be THAT hard. Thanks in advance! And sorry for the stupid question apparently...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
// Your property to get the current state from.
public bool IsChecked = false;

private void RowSelected()
{
    // Count all selected cells that have the same row-index as the first cell.
    int cellsSelected = datagridview.SelectedCells.Cast<DataGridViewCell>().Select(x => x).Where(x => x.RowIndex == datagridview.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex).Count();
    // If count of cells == count of columns -> all cells are selected.
    IsChecked = (cellsSelected == datagridview.Columns.Count) ? true : false;
}

public void DataGridView_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Will take care for the switch.
    RowSelected();
}
```

Comment: I meant exactly something like that when I said it could be done in this way, with a couple of checks and loops. But are you sure it's the only appropriate way and therefore the best as well? Thank you for the code anyway!

Comment: @D.Petrov "A couple of" sound rather like 5 methods and 3 if-else statements to me. In fact this one has just one line counting the cells and one line deciding if the count means `full row`. Thinking about the holding variable you've got 3 lines of Code. Not very much hm? Why dont you just set your `DataGridView` to `FullRowSelect`? Do you need the ability to select single cells?